# How to use START and pipe together?

Tags: windows, command-line

Originally I had a command like this (on linux)

```
daemon flag & app flag
```

However on windows bc daemon never ends app never starts. So I wrote this instead

```
start /B daemon flag & app flag
```

This appears to work. Now I'd like to run `daemon flag | app2 flags` but everything I do start complains about daemon not existing and other problems. I figure out if I put in `daemon flag | app2 flags` in `file.bat` and `start /B file.bat` instead it appears to do what I want. But that feels hackish.

How do I run `daemon flag | app2 flags` in the background and `app flag` immediately? Is that file.bat workaround my only option?

Comment: @linuxdev2013: Why are you adding the PowerShell tag when the OP hasn't indicated that he's using PowerShell?

Comment: What's the exact error you see when you run `start /b daemon flag | app2 flags`?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping everything in double quotes `start /b "daemon flag | app2 flags"` ?

Comment: @JulianKnight: Yes thats how i get the complaint about daemon not existing

Comment: @Karan: usually that the file daemon doesn't exist

Comment: OK, another approach - put the commands into a cmd file and run it. Does that work? Also, where is `daemon` installed? Are you running from the same folder or is it in the path?

Comment: @JulianKnight: Yep i already said that (in an early edit), in a bat file it will work.. IDK where it is saved tbh but on the command line it works so I suspect its somewhere in my path

Comment: You haven't really explained why you want to use `START /B` anyway. Where are you calling this from and why that way? Why not just run the batch file which would seem to be a lot simpler and actually *less* "hackish".

Comment: @JulianKnight: literally my second sentence. **bc daemon never ends app never starts**

Comment: No, we are still missing some key information. I don't think using `START` is going to help with a daemon that isn't doing what you expected.

Comment: @JulianKnight: Start lets me run the daemon and doesn't care if it returns. It runs the next command. Hence why `start /B daemon & app` runs my app. The problem here is pipe `|`

Comment: But what is the daemon outputting? I think that you might need to switch to PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you want:

```
start /B %comspec% /c "daemon flag | app2 flags" & app flag
```

This gives a new incarnation of the `cmd` shell, running in background and handling the pipe, which is done implicitly both by the use of `start` with a batch file and by the equivalent Linux command.

There will of course be confusion if `app2` and `app` both generate output, and even more confusion if both request console input (equally true of Linux and Windows).